# 7za with password not working while extraction

Tags: rhel, 7z

I am creating a password protected file using 7za, command:

```
    7za a /usr/test/loc/file.del.7za /usr/test/loc/file.del -p

....

    Creating archive /usr/test/loc/file.del.7za


    Enter password (will not be echoed) :
    Verify password (will not be echoed) :

    Everything is Ok
```

However, while extracting the files using the command: `7za e /usr/test/loc/file.del.7za`, it won't prompt me to enter the password and would extract the file. Looking at the documentation, this is not the expected working. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Actually, it turns out that 7za does not ask for a password for archives that contain empty files. Isn't it weird though!

Answer (score 0):

I had archived an empty file and had password set for it. Turns out that 7za would not ask for password when archive contains only empty files.